# parser not found for codec wmav2

Tags: ffmpeg

I am getting a warning when I run the below command.

Warning: [asf @ 01C787A0] parser not found for codec wmav2, packets or times may be inval
id.

I am using the latest ffmpeg.exe, did I miss any parameters. Any suggestions please.

```
ffmpeg -i Assets\Logitech_webcam_on_PC.wmv -sameq -f swf -y -an -s 640x360 MySlide.swf
ffmpeg version N-35295-gb55dd10, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 30 2011 00:52:52 with gcc 4.6.2
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-ru
ntime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libope
ncore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --en
able-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger -
-enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwben
c --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-
libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil    51. 29. 1 / 51. 29. 1
  libavcodec   53. 39. 1 / 53. 39. 1
  libavformat  53. 22. 0 / 53. 22. 0
  libavdevice  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
  libavfilter   2. 50. 0 /  2. 50. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
[asf @ 01C787A0] parser not found for codec wmav2, packets or times may be inval
id.

Seems stream 1 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000
/1) -> 0.08 (1/12)
Input #0, asf, from 'Assets\Logitech_webcam_on_PC.wmv':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.5721.5265
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    VBR Peak        : 50500.0000
    Buffer Average  : 66550.0000
  Duration: 00:00:36.22, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 497 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: wmav2 (a[1][0][0] / 0x0161), 32000 Hz, 1 channels,
s16, 20 kb/s
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: wmv2 (WMV2 / 0x32564D57), yuv420p, 320x180, 422 kb/
s, 0.08 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
[buffer @ 02AA9760] w:320 h:180 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/1000000 sar:0/1 sws_param:
[scale @ 02AA9A80] w:320 h:180 fmt:yuv420p -> w:640 h:360 fmt:yuv420p flags:0x4
Output #0, swf, to 'MySlide.swf':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 11.0.5721.5265
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 1
    VBR Peak        : 50500.0000
    Buffer Average  : 66550.0000
    encoder         : Lavf53.22.0
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: flv1, yuv420p, 640x360, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn,
0.08 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (wmv2 -> flv)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    4 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=      97kB time=00:00:48.00 bitrate=  16.6kbits/s
frame=    5 fps=  0 q=0.0 Lsize=     111kB time=00:01:00.00 bitrate=  15.2kbits/
s dup=0 drop=599
video:111kB audio:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.128646%
```